# PHP Mysql query coming back empty, even though there is content

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just set up a LAMP server on Ubuntu 18.04 with PHP 7.2

I'm trying to connect to a database and get content from a table, but the value returns empty every time, even though when I run the query on PHPMyAdmin it comes back with content.

Could someone assist?

```
        $get = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE id=1");           

        while($it = mysqli_fetch_array($get)) {
          $id = $it['id'];
          $firstname = $it['username'];
        }
```

Comment: If you don't print anything from the `while` loop, then how would you know either way whether or not there is a result set?  I recommend running that query directly against MySQL, and seeing if anything comes back.  If it does, then maybe try to catch an exception in your PHP script.

Comment: What does `mysqli_error($mysqli)` display? Where are you actually returning a value?

Comment: I have a <?php echo $firstname?> further down the page. After the code in the post I have this: if($firstname == ""){ $firstname = "Empty"; } and it always prints "Empty". I tried running the query in the SQL section of phpmyadmin and it comes back with the username I'm looking for.

Comment: I tried mysqli_error($mysqli) and it comes back with nothing.

Comment: Inside your loop, try `var_dump($it);` and see what comes out

Comment: I tried var_dump($it); and it returned NULL @Vlam

Comment: I suspect this is another wrong database connection issue. double check your DB config

Comment: It's resolved. Thanks people